# Load UserDict into a Postscript File

Tags: postscript

How do I store a user dictionary in one file and load the same dictionary at the beginning of another file? This should give the same result as if the dictionary was defined at the top of the same file.

More explicitely: I have written a global dictionary *ObjDict*, containing several variable and procedure definitions.

```
!%PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0

/ObjDict 30 dict def
ObjDict begin
...
/particle 
{  
     /posy exch def
     /posx exch def
     ...
} bind def
...
end %ObjDict

%%EOF
```

Now I want to call the procedure *particle* with the corresponding positions *posy posx* from a different file, that I want to be created by my simulation program. eg:

```
!%PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0

ObjDict begin
    0.5 0.5 particle
    0.1 0.0 particle
    0.3 0.3 particle
end %ObjDict

%%EOF
```

Is there a simple way to let the second file know about the dictionary ObjDict defined in the first file?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably a better fit on StackOverflow, but it's too old to migrate. Also `userdict` is a specific dictionary defined by the postscript language; other dictionaries are just called *dictionaries* or *dicts*.

It looks like you're trying to make EPS (Encapsulated PostScript) files. EPS files are intended to be self-contained. So they ought not to depend upon data from another file.

To make these regular PostScript, change the first line to

```
%!
```

or

```
%!PS
```

. Then you can use the `run` operator to run the file with the dictionary.

- (filename)   **run**   -

Also, you have not created a "global" dictionary unless you use `true setglobal` to change the allocation mode to global. But also be warned that you cannot simply use `def` with an object allocated in global memory. Objects in global memory cannot be stored in dictionaries or arrays which are in local memory (like `userdict`). So if you really need a global array, you have to put it in `globaldict`.

```
currentglobal
  true setglobal
  globaldict /ObjDict 30 dict put
setglobal
```

But you probably don't need to use global memory.